# Google Analytic - unknown traffic/tracking

Tags: google-analytics

I create a GA ID at **early June, 2016**.

- UA-XXXXX-1 is for live site and i set the URL at GA was www.example.com
- UA-XXXXX-2 is for staging site and the url for GA was www.example.com/staging

Then, I uploaded my file to staging site at **27 June, 2016** ( UA-XXXXX-2 ), tested the GA and all page tracking working good.

But when I switch to UA-XXXXX-1's GA reporting, it already got tracking data inside, may I know why? Because I didn't implement the GA code ( UA-XXXXX-1 ) before, somemore I check the userflow, it doesn't have any valid url for me to debug.

[image]
[image]

May I know is this a normal incident/error from Google Analytic?
Or somehow anything I did wrong?

Anyone has this problem previously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably bot or spam data.

The easiest way to tell is to look at the Hostname dimension, which you can do by adding it as a secondary dimension to a standard report. You'll probably see a strange hostname such as 'clickhere.xyz' or 'freesocialbuttons.xyz'. Don't try going to the site!

This kind of spam is caused by people firing off huge batches of hits to random Google Analytics IDs in the hope that someone like you will notice, and try visiting the site where it came from. Don't feed the trolls.